# How to safely pass modelinfo between different actions in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a **certain action** in my controller. 
I've created a view for it and linked a model in it... now I want to pass some info from a property from this model onto **another action** safely... Only ways I know are to pass it with @Html.ActionLink /with a hidden field in a form.

But these **aren't secure** at all as far as I know... so what other way is there to do this ?

Comment: Can you show the code? Can you explain why you think it isn't secure?

Comment: What do you mean it's not secure?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a session variable:

To store a property of the model in the first action:

```
public ViewActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
     Session["remember"] = model.someProperty;
     return View();
}
```

To retrieve it in another action:

```
public ViewResult SomeOtherAction()
{
    var rememberedValue = Session["remember"];
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This is terrible because different tabs will now interfere with each other. We all hate such web apps.